# How to split a url into key-value pairs when values are optional, in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to split a url into key/value pairs, except sometimes there are independent keys (carry no values). IE I have some urls of this format:

```
 'first_resources/99/second_resources/41/third_resources/fourth_resources/98'
```

Here, the first, second, and fourth resources have ids, but the third resource does not.

I would like to have this output an array like this:

```
[["first_resources",99],["second_resources",41],["third_resources"],["fourth_resources",98]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a relatively simple regular expression and `Array.map()` operation:

```
var re = /(\w+\/\d+)|(\w+)/g,
str = 'first_resources/99/second_resources/41/third_resources/fourth_resources/98',
results;

results = str.match(re).map(function(item) {
  return item.split('/');
})
```

Depending on your target platform, you may need to shim [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var url = window.location.href;
  url = url.split('#').pop().split('?').pop();
  var urlTrim = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  alert(urlTrim)
})
```